# Using Power series notation for equations of motion

Tags: summation

How would I simplify these expressions into power series notation in mathematica?

For example, in a 3 body system of the earth moon and sun.
Where masses are

```
Sun=M
Earth=m1
Moon=m2

Distance from sun to earth = r1
Distance from earth to moon= r2
Distance from sun to moon: r3=r2-r1
```

[image]

For example

```
\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(\[Infinity]\)]
\*FractionBox[\(1\), 
SuperscriptBox[\(i\), \(6\)]]\)
```

which gives

```
\[Pi]^6/945
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sum notation"?  Can you edit your question to give an example of what you're looking for using LaTeX?

Comment: Apologies for the delay, i've updated the question with an example.
What im struggling to see is to how i can show these equations in the above mentioned sum notation. 
Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with these equations

```
eqs = Table[
 r[k]''[t] == -G Sum[
  m[j] (r[k] - r[j])/Norm[r[k] - r[j]]^3,
  {j, Complement[{1, 2, 3}, {k}]}
 ], 
 {k, 3}
];
eqs /. {r[k_]''[t] :> Subscript[Overscript[r, ".."], k], r[k_] :> Subscript[r, k], m[k_] :> Subscript[m, k]} // Column // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  \overset{\text{..}}{r}_1=-G \left(\frac{m_2 \left(r_1-r_2\right)}{\left\| r_1-r_2\right\| {}^3}+\frac{m_3 \left(r_1-r_3\right)}{\left\| r_1-r_3\right\| {}^3}\right) \\
>  \overset{\text{..}}{r}_2=-G \left(\frac{m_1 \left(r_2-r_1\right)}{\left\| r_2-r_1\right\| {}^3}+\frac{m_3 \left(r_2-r_3\right)}{\left\| r_2-r_3\right\| {}^3}\right) \\
>  \overset{\text{..}}{r}_3=-G \left(\frac{m_1 \left(r_3-r_1\right)}{\left\| r_3-r_1\right\| {}^3}+\frac{m_2 \left(r_3-r_2\right)}{\left\| r_3-r_2\right\| {}^3}\right) \\
> \end{array}$

If you're looking for a programmatic way to typeset these equations in summation notation

```
typeset = {r[k_]''[t] :> Subscript[Overscript[r, ".."], k], r[k_] :> Subscript[r, k], m[k_] :> Subscript[m, k]};

general = HoldForm[r[k]''[t] == -G Sum[m[j] (r[k] - r[j])/Norm[r[k] - r[j]]^3, j != k]] /. typeset // TraditionalForm
```

> $\overset{\text{..}}{r}_k=-G \sum_{j\neq k} \frac{m_j \left(r_k-r_j\right)}{\left\| r_k-r_j\right\| {}^3}$

```
general /. List /@ Thread[k -> Range[3]] // Column // TraditionalForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  \overset{\text{..}}{r}_1=-G \sum _{j\neq 1} \frac{m_j \left(r_1-r_j\right)}{\left\| r_1-r_j\right\| {}^3} \\
>  \overset{\text{..}}{r}_2=-G \sum _{j\neq 2} \frac{m_j \left(r_2-r_j\right)}{\left\| r_2-r_j\right\| {}^3} \\
>  \overset{\text{..}}{r}_3=-G \sum _{j\neq 3} \frac{m_j \left(r_3-r_j\right)}{\left\| r_3-r_j\right\| {}^3} \\
> \end{array}$